# how can I return days without any order using grouped by placed date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to return all days in a month and for each day I have to return the number of orders made that day.

Order table is where I store orders that have one timestamp(created_at), id and other attributes like name, address etc.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `mwk_keys`.`orders` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `placed_date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `vendor_id` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) as total_orders,
       DAY(placed_date) as day_of_month,
       MONTH(placed_date) as month_of _year
FROM `order`
WHERE YEAR(placed_date) = 2014
GROUP BY DAY(placed_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(placed_date) ASC;
```

```
| total_orders      | day_of_month | month_of_year  |
|___________________|______________|________________|
| 49                | 27           | 1              |
| 85                | 6            | 3              |
| 96                | 16           | 4              |
| 127               | 17           | 4              |
| 104               | 18           | 4              |
| 90                | 21           | 4              |
| 79                | 2            | 4              |
| 107               | 24           | 4              |
| 114               | 3            | 4              |
| 86                | 25           | 4              |
| 84                | 7            | 4              |
| 76                | 28           | 4              |
| 114               | 9            | 4              |
| 82                | 30           | 4              |
| 124               | 11           | 4              |
| 88                | 14           | 4              |
| 126               | 15           | 4              |
| 81                | 12           | 5              |
| 92                | 13           | 5              |
| 89                | 19           | 5              |
| 83                | 20           | 5              |
```

This query returns only day that have at least one order.
I can NOT create another table or use new mysql functions.

what I want is this result:

```
| total_orders      | day_of_month | month_of_year  |
|___________________|______________|________________|
| 0                 | 1            | 1              |
| 0                 | 2            | 1              |
| 0                 | 3            | 1              |
| 0                 | 4            | 1              |
.....................................................
| 1                 | 27           | 1              |
| 0                 | 28           | 1              |
```

Comment: The GROUP BY is invalid and will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: I am using version 5.7 of MYSQL

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive CTE for date and get the number of orders for each day

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates
AS
(
SELECT '2014-01-01' as dt
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
FROM dates
WHERE dt < '2014-12-31'
)
SELECT COUNT(id), DAY(dates.dt) as day_of_month, MONTH(dates.dt) as month_of_year
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN `order` on dates.dt = `order`.placed_date
ORDER BY DAY(dates.dt), MONTH(dates.dt)
```

p.s Not very proficient with mysql

Comment: how good would scale this answer if I have to generate this report for more than 5 years not for a month

Comment: I would suggest creating a table (usually in BI it is common to create a date dimension table for these reports), then put index in both date table and the `order` and then it will not be very slow

Comment: can you give more detail how would you create the new table. I can not create a new table but I would be happy to know :).

Comment: It is essentially my CTE turned into a physical table (with many more possible columns like quarter, isholiday and other analytics-related columns). Here is a blog about it (although it is done in MSSQL the concept is still there): https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/